# browser treating JavaScript as text

Tags: javascript, html, events, properties

I am trying to make a login/register form. The onclick event doesn`t work.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
> at login (2.html:47)
> at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (2.html:16)

How can I fix it?
As I assume something wrong with style property in JS:

```
       regForm.style.transform = "translateX(400px)";
```

HTML with JavaScript in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/styles/StyleSheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="account-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-container">
                <div class="form-btn">
                    <span onclick="login()">Login</span>
                    <span onclick="register()">Register</span>
                    <hr id="indicator"/>
                </div>
                <form id="loginForm">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username or Email" />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="name" value="" />
                    <label>Remember me on this computer</label>
                    <a href="#">Forgot password</a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
                </form>
                <form id="regiterForm">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username or Email" />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var loginForm = document.getElementById("loginForm");
    var regForm = document.getElementById("regForm");
    var indicator = document.getElementById("indicator");

    function register() {
        regForm.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
        loginForm.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
 }
    function login() {
        regForm.style.transform = "translateX(400px)";
        loginForm.style.transform = "translateX(400px)";
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.account-page{
padding:50px 0;
background:radial-gradient(#0094ff,#000000)}
.form-container{
background:#fff;
width:400px;
height:400px;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
padding:20px 0;
margin:auto;
text-shadow:0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
.form-container span{
font-weight:bold;
padding:0 10px;
color:#555;
width:100px;
display:inline-block;}
.form-btn{
display:inline-block;}
.form-container form {
max-width: 400px;
padding: 0 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 130px;}
form input{
width:100%;
height:30px;
margin:10px 0;
padding:0 10px;
border:1px solid #ccc;}
form .cb{width:auto;
height:100%;
padding:0;
float:left;}
form label{
float:left;
padding:0 0 0 5px;}
form a{float:left;}
form button{float:right;}
form .btn{
width:auto;
border:none;
cursor:pointer;}
form .btn:focus{
outline:none;}
#loginForm{
left:-400px;}
#registerForm{
left:0;}
#indicator{
width:100px;
border:none;
background:#ff523b;
height:3px;
margin-top:8px;
transform:translateX(50px);}
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular note that it says "Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS." and "Include any error messages". You made a **typo** and got the ID of an element wrong.

Comment: How does your question title relate to your question? What exactly do you mean by _"browser treating JavaScript as text"_?

Comment: when I open it in browser and open dev options, it shows 
<script> Some text</script> instead of seeing as events

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at login (2.html:47)
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (2.html:16)

Comment: There is no element with the id `regForm`. There _is_ an element with the id `regiterForm`.

Answer (score -1):

I guess You should Check the console for errors..

Or If there is any error like that add `defer` attribute to your script tag.
Defer Attribute will run JavaScript only after HTML Has Loaded.

Comment: Oh as In the comments, You have messed up with the id ..   But if the problem persists, Use ```defer``` attribute in your script tag